# Chi-Squared Goodness-of-Fit... with Probabilities?

Tags: chi-squared-test

For background, I am working on a sabermetrics project where I predict probabilities of events with Naive Bayes classifiers.

I calculate the observed expected-value probability from the test-set predictions, and compare that to the expected ("true") frequency of said event in the same set.

Does a chi-squared GOF test fit here to say whether or not the observed probabilities hail from the distribution, approximately shown by a histogram-turned-frequency-plot?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! It sounds like you might be interested in something called probability calibration.

Comment: Neat, thanks! Just looked it up, and it describes well what I'm after! Thanks for the tip!